# SFML not responding after loading multiple textures and sprites

Tags: c++, crash, window, sfml

I have coded many things in SFML but never have I had this problem, I have the most simple calls and I decide to wait because this is what will happen later on in the code so I wanted to test it, and this makes my window unresponsive for whatever reason, here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1400), "R-TYPE");
    game_state screen;
    screen = game_state::MENU;
    menu menu_state;
    game game_state;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        if (screen == game_state::MENU)
            menu_state.menu_screen(screen, window);
        else if (screen == game_state::GAME)
            game_state.game_screen(screen, window);
        else if (screen == game_state::END)
            return (0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the rest

```
int menu::menu_screen(game_state &screen, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    sf::Event event;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        if (animating == true)
            menuAnimation(window);
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            handle_window(window, event);
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                    window.close();
                    return 0;
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return) {
                    screen = game_state::GAME;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}


void menu::menuAnimation(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{

    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time loopTime = sf::seconds(10.0f);
    while (clock.getElapsedTime() < loopTime) {
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }


    window.clear();
    animating = false;
}


void menu::handle_window(sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Event event)
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

I really can't seem to understand why, and if I replace the menuAnimation with anything that takes that long, such as a while loop that does things on screen for that amount of time "for animating purposes, it still does the same thing does anyone have a clue as to what it could be?[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxT5e.png)

The list is way too long but I have tried pretty much everything in my knowledge..

Comment: I'll put this here just in case someone has the same problem but I doubt it, in any while loop, you need to poll events for closing the window for example, or else it will crash because even if you draw the window or do things, the window still needs to handle events or else it crashes

Comment: If you solved your problem, you can just post an answer instead of commenting on it. Yes, any program needs to handle events to be considered active by the OS and not be flagged as "irresponsive". Different OSes may handle that differently of course.